# storing file size of a file in variable Streamlit

Tags: python, filesize, streamlit

I am trying to create a file size restriction in streamlit. For this I need to get the uploaded file size of a into a varible.

In a simple python script i was able to use the following function to get file size.

```
os.path.getsize("filename.mp3")
```

But I am unable to do it in streamlit app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In streamlit you can use the file uploader widget `st.file_uploader` in order to upload a file:

```
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Choose a file")
```

To get the size of the uploaded file we need two steps:

1. get the uploaded file bytes using getvalue():

   ```
    bytes_data = uploaded_file.getvalue()
   ```
2. get the size by using the python built in len() function on the bytes:

   ```
    file_size = len(bytes_data)
   ```

All together:

```
import streamlit as st

# upload file
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Choose a file")
if uploaded_file is not None:
    # To read file as bytes:
    bytes_data = uploaded_file.getvalue()
    # get file size
    file_size  = len(bytes_data)
```

Also a note about file size, in Streamlit by default, uploaded files are limited to 200MB. You can configure this using the server.maxUploadSize config option. For more you can read in there [documentation](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/configuration#set-configuration-options)